# After compiling Qemu 5.2.50, no VGA in Gui

Tags: qemu

I am on Devuan "chimaera", kernel 5.9.0-4-amd64 and trying to compile qemu 5.2.50 from source

There were no issues configuring and compiling qemu, but when I launch the compiled executable, only "compatmonitor0" is available, no VGA option is listed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULmvZ.png

These are the configure options I used:

```
../configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-system --enable-sdl --enable-gtk --enable-vte --enable-kvm --enable-bzip2 --enable-linux-user --enable-docs --enable-gnutls --enable-nettle --enable-curses --enable-modules --enable-virtfs --enable-curl --enable-fdt --enable-rdma --enable-vde --enable-linux-aio --enable-cap-ng --enable-attr --enable-vhost-net --enable-spice --enable-rbd --enable-libiscsi --enable-libnfs --enable-smartcard --enable-libusb --enable-usb-redir --enable-lzo --enable-snappy --enable-seccomp --enable-coroutine-pool --enable-glusterfs --enable-tpm --enable-numa --enable-opengl --enable-virglrenderer --enable-tcmalloc --enable-linux-io-uring
```

This is the configure output:
https://pastebin.com/raw/NAfPduAa

I am currently out of ideas what is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

It happened that I needed to build qemu from source on the same day as you, and after hours of torture and my own stupidity, at last I tried to install it from AUR by installing `qemu-git`. After it finally installed I noticed that there is no VGA either. So I was pretty sure that it's not my `./configure` options, but rather developers decision to remove VGA from there or something. Maybe it's a bug. But the main thing I succeded in doing is just downloading older, but stable release `5.2.0` and when I built it, it had VGA and everything was working correctly. So if you don't have the urge to install bleeding edge `qemu`, you can download stable version's source code and compile that, instead of the latest one. Hope I could help.

TLDR: Download older version, in my case it was 5.2.0

Comment: It is exactly like you said: with Version 5.2.0 the VGA option is back again. This version is sufficient for me. Next time I am going to try other versions first before wasting so much time. Thank you, Timur.

Comment: @Peter Glad I could help.